# How to open URL to open the external email sending app from TWebBrowser in FireMonkey mobile application

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, twebbrowser

I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin for developing a mobile application for iOS and Android which has the `TWebBrowser` component. In this, I have loaded a webpage with this code in it:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
<a href="mailto:sample@gmail.com?subject=Test">sample@gmail.com</a>
```

When the first label is clicked, the link is opening inside the `TWebBrowser` itself. As per my requirements, it should open in an external browser instead.

When the second label is clicked, the external email sending app is not opening.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Do I need to add anything in the webpage, or do I need to add anything to the Delphi code?

Comment: This is probably more related to the settings of your phone/tablet.

Comment: Ideally, you would simply intercept URL clicks and delegate them to the underlying OS to open them in external apps. However, `TWebBrowser` simply does not support that. Although it does have an `OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest` event for intercepting URLs, it doesn't actally work correctly. Find another component to use, or else use the underlying browser APIs directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau why do you say that OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest not work corectly? Which issues you have. Under Seattle it work for me without any problem.

Comment: @Livius it is not implemented on all platforms, and it doesn't expose a way to actually stop the navigation that is in progress so you can do something else with the URL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i forgot that i have fixed it manualy on Android - by changing calling sequence in TAndroidWebBrowserService.DoNavigate i put there ShouldStartLoading(NewURL);before LoadURLInUIThread(NewURL) and then simple in event i can call Abort to stop navigation :)

Comment: unsurprisingly @RemyLebeau is correct, both about the process and the issue with OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest. You have said you are using iOS which you can call directly to the browser (see native controls) this will work on Android as well, though there is a small difference and you should use a compiler directive to separate your platform specific code.